# $f(x)=1$, for every $x \in [0,1]$ if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $f(p)=1$ for every $p\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How would you approach this if I have to use the fact that "every number is a sequence of rational numbers"?  Currently, I am proving this by contradiction in the following way:

Let f(p)=1 for all rational p in [0,1]
Assume, by contradiction that there is at least one x in interval [0,1] s.t. f(x) is not 1. There's a contradiction here because it would no longer be continuous.

All I see here is a function not really a sequence...

Comment: I take it from reading the text of your question that the title should read "$f(x) = 1$ for *all* rational $p$ in $[0, 1]$"; you might wish to edit the title accordingly; it's false as stated.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in [0,1]$, then $x$ is a limit of a sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$. 
Indeed,
$$
\mathbb Q\ni q_n=\frac{\lfloor n x\rfloor}{n}\to x,
$$
and as $f$ is continuous, then
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=1.
$$

Comment: just a typo. the numerator should be $\lfloor nx\rfloor$

Comment: @DavidHolden: Thanks - Corrected it.

Comment: nice technique btw - the simplest idea to do the job gives lucidity

Comment: Why exactly did you think of using the floor function?

Comment: It is a standard way to approximate reals by rationals.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Do you know that if $f$ is a continuous function and $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f\big(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n\big)$?.. That is, if $f$ is continuous and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x)$.

If you know this, let $x \in [0,1]$ be arbitrary and let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ converging to $x$...

Comment: @DavidHolden I think your comment is for a different answer..?

Comment: you're right. not sure how the glitch happened so sorry about that, the comment was meant for Yiorgos. i'll try and correct it

Comment: How would you finish this proof?